# How to debug a MS server connection issue using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pymssql

Trying to connect to a remote MS Server 2008 using python 3.5, SQLalchemy 1.0.12 and pymssql 2.1.2 dialect. I'm able to connect via excel database query. The Server management studio has enabled for external connections.

```
server = "mssql+pymssql://<login>:<password>@<server>?charset=utf8"

engine = create_engine(server)
connection = engine.connect()
```

Error msg:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pymssql.InterfaceError) Connection to
>   the database failed for an unknown reason.

Looking for any help on how and where to start my debug.

Comment: Try connecting as a regular db connection: `pymssql.connect(constr)`. Also, is SQL Server services running? Check your Task Manager / Services.

Comment: Verify that the "SQL Server Browser" service is running on the remote machine.

Comment: Works using the windows authentication construct as below.                          "mssql://<server>/<database?trusted_connection=yes;driver=SQL+server"